# How to get Imported type libraries from an OCX or TLB file?

Tags: com, import, idl, tlb

I was convinced that there is no way to find COM dependencies of an ActiveX but to my surprise OLEVIEW shows some comments Like:

// TLib :     // TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
// TLib : Visual Basic runtime objects and procedures : {EA544A21-C82D-11D1-A3E4-00A0C90AEA82}
    importlib("3");

I tried to extract the same information using TypeLibInfoFromFile but based on what I find in MSDN, there is no Api that provides this information. Are you aware of a method to extract this information from OCX or it's Tlb file? Knowing that all my ocxes are compiled with vb6 can I trust this informaion for Imported(Explicitly not in code)  interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've found the answer to this question. I'll write it here just in case someone would search for the same question. It's possible to find some of dependencies but you can never be sure if you have found them all. Basically you must enumerate every type and interface, and every member of each type to find all types in the module and for every type you find you should check to see if it's in an external TypeLib. in the end you have a List of Typelibs referenced.

The problem with this method lays in the fact you find only the types that are used in the public interface (fields, return values and parameters) and you miss every local object or dynamically created ones. That said you can check this link for an [implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2008/10/06/reflection-on-com-objects.aspx) or better yet [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347981.aspx).